# Wordpress Membership Site

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a Wordpress Membership site, I would need a plugin with the following functionality : 
 1. Able to hide pages from non logged in users.
 2. New user accounts are created only by the administrator.
 3.Users can not access admin dashboard.
 4. Each user has a front-end custom profile page editable only by the admin.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the plugin on your own? We aren't a detective service. As well this question should be posted in the [WordPress StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I did , but i did not find a solution that would resolve of the questions i have .

Comment: I mean no hostility toward you, just making a point. For the future, questions regarding the specifics of WordPress should be asked on the above-linked WordPress StackExchange site. You should also mention that you have done your own sleuthing and came up with nothing... must sort out the rabble somehow, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.amember.com/ is a great option which integrates with WordPress to create a membership website.